# How to get frame by frame images from movie file in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

In iOS, I would like to get frame-by-frame images from a movie file,
I tried it by using AVAssetImageGenerator. But it gets one image per second for a 30fps movie. It should be 30images!

I heard that there is a way to use FFmpeg.
But in newer OSs like iOS7, is there a new API to do this without using external libraries like FFmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try OpenCV to capture the frames. But the speed will be dependent on the device and processor. Hope for iPhone5 the speed is perfect to capture all the frames. You can have a look at this [link](http://rashidkhaleefa.blogspot.in/2013/09/real-time-video-processing-in-iphone.html) if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to try it on iPhone5s, I don't have to worry about speed. I will also refer to link.